# Can you restore a word document from 97-2003 only using its Compound File streams?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, ole, word-2003

I am trying to recover a word document that was using 97-2003 version. I do not remember why I did this, but I saved off the [Compound File streams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYVAC.png) into a folder, and it is definitely something I would like to have back as the original document. Is there any solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "saved off compound files into a folder." It may be clear to you, but not clear to me. Do you mean you took the streams in the compound file and saved them as separate files in a folder, or what? A Word 97-2003 file (.doc) is a compound file.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson, that's exactly it. I meant streams sorry.

Comment: My reputation is not high since this is my first post so I can't display the image inline, but you can click Compound Files to see what the folder has in it. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you should theoretically be able to restore it.

You should be able to create a root compound document using

```
StgCreateDocfile() // or StgCreateStorageEx()
```

You will need the `IStorage*` pointer from this if it succeeds.

If you have a folder in your folder, you are going to have to create sub storages for each folder--and do it recursively. The API is `IStorage::CreateStorage()` ... look it up.

If you have a file in a folder, then a stream needs to be created in the storage that is equivalent to the folder. To create a stream, use `IStorage::CreateStream()`...look up arguments.

Looking at your screen shot, it has some streams named something like [1]CompObj or [5]SummaryDocumentInformation.  For the [n] part, that is probably the equivalent of _T('\00n') where n is 1 or 5 or whatever--it's probably a control character. I've seen that in compound files. If you want to investigate, create a Word 97-2003 document and save as a .doc file and examine the structure.

So, something like  [1]CompObj is really _T("\001CompObj")

The stuff above about [n] in your file names is an educated/experienced guess.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm glad there's a path forward for me to try. I hope to address this by the weekend.